# PHP/Apache, options +indexes in htaccess doesn't work for root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory-listing

I need to offer a **directory listing of the root directory** of my site, so I created an **.htaccess** file containing

```
options +indexes
```

It works for subdirectories, but for the main directory I get the **Test Page for the Apache HTTP Server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux** page.

I have two sites that are identical except for the **PHP version** installed. On one site (**PHP 5.2.1**) this technique works fine. On the other (**PHP 5.2.9**), it doesn't.

As far as I know, the **Apache** installations are identical, and I verified that the **httpd.conf files are identical**.

On both sites, the htaccess works for subdirectories. My problem is with the main site directory.

My goal is to create simple sites based on directory listings, similar to **[znvy.com](http://znvy.com)**.

Is there something about the updated PHP version that **prevents listing a root directory**? If so is there a **workaround**?

**[update]** I looked at the page using **[rex swain's http viewer](http://rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi?http://yoursite.com)** and the server of the problem site is returning a 403 status with the Apache default page.

Comment: This sounds like permissions, either on the root directory or on the htaccess file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the **/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf** file:

```
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
```

That file overrides the htaccess and turns indexing off for any root web directory. **Renaming it to welcome.con** and restarting the server solved the problem.

Comment: It would be better to rename welcome.conf.bak so that someone coming along later could understand the situation at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your main directory have an index.html or index.php file? I believe +Indexes only shows if a default document doesn't exist in the directory.

Comment: No, I renamed the default pages to eliminate that possibility. And, if that were the problem, I would see my page instead of a default Apache page.